# How to use the GitHub Fetch API polyfill

Tags: javascript, npm, polyfills, fetch-api

I would like to use a polyfill for `fetch()` so that my code runs on Safari using the [GitHub Fetch Polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch), but I'm not sure how to use it.

According to its documentation, I can install it with:

```
$ npm install whatwg-fetch --save
```

I have done this step.

I've already tried this, but it does not work:

```
var fetch = require('whatwg-fetch') // does not work
```

How am I suppose to use the fetch polyfill?

---

References:

- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- [GitHub Fetch Polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)
- [Can I use `fetch()`?](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)

Comment: More than implementing, what you want is to use the polyfill. Maybe you could change the name of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, install using

```
npm install --save whatwg-fetch
```

then use:

```
require('whatwg-fetch')
```

You can *alternatively* use `import` syntax

```
import 'whatwg-fetch'
```

The above method will require you to use **browserify**.

Another way (without requiring browserify) is to download the `fetch.js` file and place it in your project folder and then in your `index.html` use:

```
<script src="fetch.js"></script>
```